# Delete many decimal

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I have problem with a simple function in JavaScript if I add `0.0001` + `0.0001` + `0.0001` i have `0.0002999999999999999999` I don't know why because it's simple `Number(x) + Number(y)`.

With php I use this function and it's work perfectly

```
$number = number_format($number, 10, '.', '');
$number = rtrim(rtrim($number, '0'), '.');
```

What is the equivalent of this script PHP in Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: What did you try so far in javascript as for this equivalent?

Comment: [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use toFixed to convert it to a string with some decimal places shaved off, and then convert it back to a number.

```
+(0.0001 + 0.0001).toFixed(12) // 0.0002
```

It looks like IE's toFixed has some weird behavior, so if you need to support IE something like this might be better:

```
Math.round((0.0001 + 0.0001) * 1e12) / 1e12
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running into errors with floating point storage of numbers which isn't perfect. If you know exactly what precision you need, you can use the `toFixed` function to display the number as a string:

```
var x = 0.0001 + 0.0001 + 0.0001;
console.log(x.toFixed(4));
// "0.0003"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this using [toFixed():](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
var x = 0.0001 + 0.0001 + 0.0001;
alert(x.toFixed(4));
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/krwxpnz9/)

Also note that Javascript uses 64 bit floating point representation and follow [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_formats) for float.

Answer (score 1):

You may take help of toFixed to convert it to string and then convert it back to a number.

```
+(0.0001 + 0.0001).toFixed(12) // 0.0002
```

In case of IE you may write like this

```
Math.round((0.0001 + 0.0001) * 1e12) / 1e12
```